# PHP Mongodb inner document updation

Tags: php, mongodb, sql-update, php-mongodb

I have gone through a lot of questions on SO but no luck.

I am trying to `update` one field of the database.

My one record is like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53e82f244019968f9eb32f8e"),
        "date" : "12/12/14",
        "dishes" : [
                {
                        "dishname" : "sushi",
                        "quantity" : "4",
                        "price" : "10",
                        "total" : 30,
                        "rating" : "3"
                },
                {
                        "dishname" : "pad thai",
                        "quantity" : "2",
                        "price" : "10",
                        "total" : 20,
                        "rating" : "0"
                }
        ],
        "orderid" : "1234",
        "rating" : "4",
        "sum" : "50"
}
```

I want to update the `'rating'` field of dishes.

I tried this so far:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$orders = $m->ordertable->ordertable;
$order = $orders->findOne(array('orderid' => '1234'));
$newdata = array('$set' => array("dishes"=> array("rating" => "11")));
```

It's giving me error like:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\WWW\bootstrap-3.2.0\docs\examples\carousel\ajax\rating.php on line 36

Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on a non-object in C:\WWW\bootstrap-3.2.0\docs\examples\carousel\ajax\rating.php on line 36
```

Forgive me if I am wrong, but I am stuck here. It's working for simple document but I am not able
to update the field inside the inner document.

Please help.

**EDIT:**

Schema:

```
> show dbs;
local   0.078125GB
menu    0.203125GB
ordertable      0.203125GB
project 0.203125GB                   //The DB I am using
test    0.203125GB


> db.orders.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53e88de4ab129b4b8094eeba"),
        "orderid" : "1234",
        "dishes" : [
                {
                        "dishname" : "sushi",
                        "quantity" : "4",
                        "price" : "10",
                        "total" : 30,
                        "rating" : "3"
                },
                {
                        "dishname" : "pad thai",
                        "quantity" : "2",
                        "price" : "10",
                        "total" : 20,
                        "rating" : "0"
                }
        ],
        "sum" : "50",
        "date" : "12/12/14"
}
>
```

My final code:

```
$m = new MongoClient();

$orders = $m->project->orders;

$orders->update(
        array(
           array('orderid' => '1234'),
           array('dishes.dishname' => 'sushi') 
            ),
            array(
           '$set' => array( 'dishes.$.rating' => '5')
            )
    );
```

Comment: Which element of dishes? `$set` is the way to do it, but not in the way you are using it. There are examples in the documentation.

Comment: Can you please post one according to my demo record? I want to change the `rating` field of each `dish` field. I am sorry to ask but can you please provide me the ex code. I went through the documentation already :/

Answer (score 0):

You basically want the [`.update()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php) method for which [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) is an operator used within this method, as it does nothing by itself. The other thing is you need to know the "array position" at which to update. The best way to do this is within the "query" portion of the update, and using the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator to report the position.

For example, to update "sushi" do this:

```
$orders->update(
   array( 'orderid' => '1234', 'dishes.dishname' => 'sushi' ),
   array(
       '$set' => array( 'dishes.$.rating' => 11 )
   )
);
```

So the "query" portion of `.update()` is the first argument which selects the document, and also has additional information to identify the array element in "dishes". The "update" portion uses the `$set` operator to only change the specified field. The `$` in the middle of the notation tells the statement to update at the "index" matching from the "query" portion before.

Generally you also want to use the ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) form as shown to identify the sub-document fields within the array.

The MongoDB official documentation as well as the PHP docs are there to help.

Comment: thanks for the reply but its not updating. I even tried to fetch a single `order` from `orders` and update that (i know it's not the way) but it says can't update `order`. When I run your code, I get no error or warning, so there is no way I can tell you what is wrong. EDIT: I even tried `$push`.

Comment: I even tried the `array( 'orderid' => '1234' )` and `array('dishes.dishname' => 'sushi')` singularly to find out if its getting the `orders` and it's working fine.

Comment: @ADi Working fine means what? You need to match the array position so only the second form would work as the only query argument. If it does not work as shown then your document does not actually match the same specifications as shown. So "orderid" and "dishes.dishname" do not match the same data specification that you have posted. i.e "Works for me" the way you have posted and with the answer.